# Does the keyword blog in url impove seo?

Tags: seo, url, blog

I have seen a couple of site which has high number of hits. They are mostly tutorial sites and blogs that address software issue/errors. I wonder if the keyword "blog" has a very positive effect in SEO?

In my own site, I have installed Wordpress in root folder to avoid any blog keyword. I also did this to keep urls shallow (deeper url are not good for SEO). But I may want to think on it again. The sites I am referring too are

```
http://blog.sqlauthority.com
http://veerasundar.com/blog/2011/11/making-xampp-to-serve-any-directory-outside-htdocs/
```

I know there are standard (sort of) class names or  ID that identify different contents and makes it easier for the search engine to identify contents like, "container", "menu". The use of word "blog" would mean this is about dicussing/tutoring something and have a very positive effect on SEO?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, using the word "blog" or having a blog does not give a web site or web page a boost in the search results (there are no arbitrary bonuses in search). There is nothing special about blogs and are not favored in any way. Those sites you found rank well because they have quality content that people are looking for. Even if that content wasn't in a blog format it would still rank well (I.e. it was an article site or even a Q&A site).

Comment: Unless of course the user is searching for "blog" :)